# Job scheduled in Spoon (PDI) doesn't stop running in Pentaho Server (CE)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

At first, I'm using Spoon (PDI) and Pentaho Server (Community Edition).

I created a job in Spoon, in my computer, and saved it in my the Pentaho Server repository.

In the 'Start' of this job I put a schedule, just for testing purposes, to run every 5 minutes.

After saving it, nothing happened in the beginning (job didn't run after 5 min), but then when I manually ran it into Pentaho User Console admin from Server, it didn't stop anymore.

Since Spoon (CE) doesn't have Schedule perspective, and also in Pentaho User Console this job was not Schedule, I can't stop it.

It keeps running in my server every 5 minutes. I've already saved another version of the file without scheduling, but didn't work.

Does anyone knows how to stop it?

Comment: Until you do not stop the job manually it will not stop. That is how pentaho job execution works in community version.
You can use cron-tab or windows scheduler for the same.

Comment: @HelpingHand..
hi! So, where can I manually stop it? I access http://.../pentaho/kettle/status/ and could find them and exclude, but it is still running. Any ideia?