# How to unschedule a job or kill scheduler When you have scheduled a job using START STEP of a job In Pentaho DI?

Tags: mysql, pentaho, scheduler, job-scheduling, pentaho-data-integration

I have scheduled a job to run daily using START STEP of a job and Not using the Schedule Prespective, Now i can't locate it in scheduled jobs, but the job runs daily for a specific date and i want to kill the scheduler and stop this Job.How to do do so ?

I tried checking scheduled jobs in Schedule prespective, Checked logs to locate the scheduled jobs But failed

Answer (score 0):

I think a similar question was asked in
[Job scheduled in Spoon (PDI) doesn't stop running in Pentaho Server (CE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65617550/job-scheduled-in-spoon-pdi-doesnt-stop-running-in-pentaho-server-ce)

You can use cron-tab or windows scheduler – Helping Hand..Jan 8, 2021 at 10:57

Comment: Nah thats different Can any one inform about cron tab method to kill a scheduled job